# Redirect to base URL doesn't work

Tags: php

I need to make members only access to my `index.php` page. So my php script at the beginning of my `index.php` file is checking if user name is in session, and if it's not it should automatically redirect user to my `login.php` page.
So my login page should be BASE_URL page. I also did `define ('BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.com/login.php');` in my `verify.php` script.
But when I navigate to my index page I only get (blank screen) error "An error occurred in script'path/index.php' on line 11: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at path/index.php:1)".
I don't have any spaces before my HTML, that may be the cause. I also tried to set BASE_URL to my login with "base_href" in `head` of my `login.php`, but didn't worked.
This is my script at the begining of my index file:

```
<?php 
require_once ('verify.php'); 
$page_title = 'title';
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($page_title)) {
$page_title = 'title';}
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {    
$url = BASE_URL . ''; 
ob_end_clean();
header("Location: $url ");
exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

My `verify.php` content:

```
<?php 
define('LIVE', TRUE);
define('EMAIL', 'my_mail');
define ('BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.com/login.php');
define ('MYSQL', 'db.php');
function my_error_handler ($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
$message = "<p>An error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line:      $e_message\n<br />"; 
$message .= "Date/Time: " . date('n-j-Y H:i:s') . "\n<br />";
$message .= "<pre>" . print_r ($e_vars, 1) . "</pre>\n</p>";
if (!LIVE) { echo '<div class="error">' . $message . '</div><br />';

} else {        
    mail(EMAIL, 'Site Error!', $message, 'From: you@youremail.com');
    if ($e_number != E_NOTICE) {
    echo '<div class="error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div><br />';
    }   }     } 
 set_error_handler ('my_error_handler');
 ?>
```

Comment: show your verify content

Comment: probably related to your output buffering. you can test if headers have already been sent via to see at which point in the code the headers have in fact already been sent.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Comment: @DavidNguyen I updated with my verify content.

Comment: You do not obtain anything before the error? Please check the source code to see if there's any html tag.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos in my source code of my blank screen are `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` ..only that.

Comment: Also when I register or login `login.php` redirect me to my `index.php` correctly with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The answer is to encode in UTF8 without BOM.